# Alignment issue in SAP Work Manager (Agentry)

Tags: sap-smp

AGENTRY-IPAD deployment

I am trying to add a new custom field under notification details in "workorderdetailscreen(Ipad)", But when I set the alignment, it is showing up slightly below the required position overlapping on the below field(not completely changing the row too) When I set the height to 1, It is aligning correctly but when the height is changed from auto to 1, there is an edit option appearing beside the field("i" symbol in Ipad)which implies to edit the field so is there a way I could align correctly and get rid of the edit option beside it as well?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Removing the Dummy Wrapper from the object property in the field and populating the field by giving the Rule gives the result, even if you increase the height it will not give the Edit "i" Symbol